# Git Submodule - add files from a repository to a folder as submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I confused the concept of Git submodules.

I created separate repositories intended to be submodules of another project, then in the main project repository I added empty folders to where these files should be added.

example:

```
MyProject/
   ./lib
   ./headers
   ./source
```

those folders are empty because the contents will be coming from the separate repos as submodules but the thing is that they are named differently.
the contents of `lib/` will be coming from `lib_trunk` submodule and source is called `source_trunk`

is there a way to tweak the submodules feature in git to instead clone the repo as named it will just add the files contained in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create the folders in advance, git will do it for you. And those folders can be named differently than the -submodule- repositories they contain.

> git submodule add `url/to/lib_trunk` `lib`

will initialize a submodule in a `lib` folder from a repository called `lib_trunk`. Same thing with `source`.

If, as you say, both `lib` and `source` already exist, you may have to delete them before doing `git submodule add` (but as they're empty there is no reason to keep them).